# DoctrineMongoDBBundle: Specify Read Preference to Document Manager

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-mongodb

I'm connecting to a remote database that is configured only for reading.
If I use:

```
$connection = new \MongoClient($server);                               
$dbname = $connection->selectDB("db");
$dbname->setReadPreference(\MongoClient::RP_SECONDARY);
```

It works fine, but if I try:

```
$dm = $this->getDocumentManager(); //using remote db connection in config
$result = $dm->getRepository('Repository')->method();
```

I get this error:

> not master and slaveOk=false

How can I specify the Read Preference to the $dm, same way as it works for the MongoClient?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
We have to specify the readPreference property in the config.yml file.
Hope this can help anyone else...

```
conn2:
   server: "%conn2_server%"
     options:
      connect: true
      db: "%conn2_options_db%"
      readPreference: secondary
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better use:

```
readPreference: secondaryPreferred
```

or

```
readPreference: primaryPreferred
```

Instead of simply primary or secondary, because if primary or secondary it's not aviable with the preferred option you can still retrieve data from other node.